# Python Socket - Cannot listen

Tags: python, sockets

i wrote a python socket script. Is there anyway i can listen by opening up my own .HTML page on localhost? I would basically like to listen when i open my own HTML page, i just dont know what folder to put it in.

```
import socket
import sys

HOST = socket.gethostbyname('localhost')
PORT = 8080

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print("Socket Created!!")

try:
    s.bind((HOST, PORT))
except socket.error as msg:
    print("Bind failed. Error Code: " + str(msg[0]) + "Message: " + msg[1])
    sys.exit()  
print("Socket bind complete")

s.listen(10)
print('Socket now listening')

while True: 
    connectionSocket, addr = s.accept()
    print('source address:' + str(addr))
    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
        print('message = ' + str(message))
        filename = message.split()[1] 
        print('filename = ' + str(filename))
        f = open(filename[1:], 'rb') 
        outputdata = f.read()
        headerLine = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK \r\n content-type:text/html \r\n charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n"
        connectionSocket.send(headerLine.encode())
        print(outputdata)
        connectionSocket.send(outputdata)
        connectionSocket.close()
        print("Connection closed!")
    except IOError:
        headerLine = "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found \r\n content-type:text/html \r\n charset=utf-8 \r\n\r\n"
        connectionSocket.send(headerLine.encode())
        connectionSocket.send("<h3>404 Not Found</h3>".encode())
        connectionSocket.close()

serverSocket.close()
```

Comment: for clarity, are you trying to close the socket once the endpoint is hit?

Comment: @Peter Yes i am. Does it make a difference? Sorry not familiar with it.

Comment: Your code just works, what's the problem?

Comment: Do you probably have another process holding the port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several issues going on here.

The provided code just works. You're trying to open file which is located in the working directory of the python process, executing the script. For example if your're running something like

```sh
python script.py
```

the HTML file should reside in the same directory with the script.

```
$ ls .
script.py
index.html
```

However if you're running the script from another directory or setting working directory when running your script, the HTML file should reside in that location.

You can even change the working directory from within your script with [os.chdir()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html?highlight=os%20chdir#os.chdir) method. for example for your code:

```py
import socket
import sys
import os


HOST = socket.gethostbyname('localhost')
PORT = 8080
HTML_ROOT = '/var/www/html'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    os.chdir(HTML_ROOT)
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    print("Socket Created!!")

    try:
        s.bind((HOST, PORT))
    except socket.error as msg:
        print("Bind failed. Error Code: " + str(msg[0]) + "Message: " + msg[1])
        sys.exit()
    print("Socket bind complete")

    s.listen(10)
    print('Socket now listening')

    while True:
        connectionSocket, addr = s.accept()
        print('source address:' + str(addr))
        try:
            message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
            print('message = ' + str(message))
            filename = message.split()[1]
            print('filename = ' + str(filename))
            f = open(filename[1:], 'rb')
            outputdata = f.read()
            headerLine = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK \r\n content-type:text/html \r\n charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n"
            connectionSocket.send(headerLine.encode())
            print(outputdata)
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata)
            connectionSocket.close()
            print("Connection closed!")
        except IOError:
            headerLine = "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found \r\n content-type:text/html \r\n charset=utf-8 \r\n\r\n"
            connectionSocket.send(headerLine.encode())
            connectionSocket.send("<h3>404 Not Found</h3>".encode())
            connectionSocket.close()

    serverSocket.close()
```

Comment: I put the HTML file in the same directory that my python script is at and its saying Socket 'Created!! Socket bind complete Socket now listening' but then nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

you can just do this--no need to keep it in a while loop

```
message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
print('message = ' + str(message))
filename = message.split()[1] 
print('filename = ' + str(filename))
f = open(filename[1:], 'rb') 
outputdata = f.read()
headerLine = "HTTP/1.1 200 OK \r\n content-type:text/html \r\n charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n"
connectionSocket.send(headerLine.encode())
print(outputdata)
connectionSocket.send(outputdata)
connectionSocket.close()

s.close()
```

Edit for context:
you aren't closing the socket or exiting the While , so once you are receiving your data, it's expecting additional connections/messages

Comment: Where would i put my HTML file so it can listen?

Comment: So my understanding based on your comment was that you just wanted to hit an endpoint and end the listen. you wouldn't need a HTML file for this

Comment: Are you trying to load a webpage and then close the connection after that one connection ends? I may not understand your issue fully.

Comment: I want to run my HTML page and have the socket print out the HTTP header info like HTTP/1.1 200 OK \r\n content-type:text/html \r\n charset=utf-8\r\n\r\n

Comment: would i need a webserver?

Comment: I need to run for a while so I may not have time to address this quickly but I promise to look back. My questions for you are -> Are you just trying to host an WebPage? -> Are you tied to using SocketServer? Sounds like something like Flask would be a lot easier for you

Comment: Actually, I would look below. It looks like Roberts post has what you want